# How to find IAM user who registered a new domain on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudtrail

I'd like to find which IAM user registered a new domain in route53 from our AWS account. How can I do this?

The domain is registered a week ago and I tried to check CreateDomain, CreateDomainEntry, CreateDomainName in cloudtrail in the past 3 weeks and found no records for these event names.

I also tried to find route53resolver.amazonaws.com, route53.amazonaws.com, route53domains.amazonaws.com in EventSource but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Did you check CloudTrial history or logs?

Comment: I tried to check in cloudtrail using event name as createdomain, createdomainentry, createdomainname and no records are found

Comment: So search for any Route53 activity.

Comment: Searched for EventSource route53resolver.amazonaws.com, route53.amazonaws.com,  route53domains.amazonaws.com. There is nothing

Comment: You need to search for the correct event name. This is the place to start: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_Operations_Amazon_Route_53_Domains.html

Answer (score 1):

I would still dig into CloudTrail (if it was indeed a week ago!) looking for `RegisterDomain`, `CreateHostedZone` and `ChangeResourceRecordSets`

Comment: I've tried it by putting a filter of last 12 weeks and there's not a single matching result available

Comment: CloudTrail records expire after 90 days (unless you copy them to S3).  Did you set `ReadOnly = false`?

Comment: It is possible it was created long time ago, you just did not notice.  You can break routing on the domain and see who tries to fix it when TTL expires ;)